# Asp.net session storage

Tags: asp.net, session

Are there any pre-conditions before storing any objects in session state.
I mean when will I not be able to insert an object in session state.
This was an interview question that was asked to me.
What could be the possible reason for not being able to store an object in session state?

Comment: Hello. Where are you storing session? (in-proc, in a database, ...)

Comment: Serializable, obviously - or did you mean something else?

Comment: Did you mean to ask: When should I not use InProc Session state? Or: Will the framework validate my objects before storing them in memory when using InProc?

Comment: Could it be the simplest answer?: when you don't need to persist variables across multiple pages. Was the question asking when you should not store items in session, or when you unable to store items in session.

Comment: Question was what could be the possible reason for not being able to store a particular type of object while other objects could be stored.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some that should be considered:

- If it has more session data, then more memory is consumed on the web server, and that can affect performance.
- It won't work in [web garden mode](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/10/01/what-is-the-difference-between-web-farm-and-web-garden/), because in that mode multiple aspnet_wp.exe will be running on the same machine.
- And if the appdomain or worker process (aspnet_wp.exe) restart/recycles very often then its not a good idea to use it

and it is gathered from [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/c3e1fc0b-3ea0-4955-af1e-2c052a55cd23/aspnet-session-how-to-faqs.aspx) ... hope it answer your query ...

Answer (score 3):

There are places in the asp.net page request life-cycle that you do not have access to the session state yet due to the lack of a valid user session such as Application_Authorize where we do not have an authenticated user yet, so Session will be null. The actual implementation of the Session store shouldn't really be a concern, neither should how the data is serialized.